# How do I know my react-native app is working smoothly and is not at risk?

Tags: react-native

Is there a good way to know our react-native app is working well?

although I know there is a `perf monitor` When I enable `Perf Monitor`, here is some options which I dont know what do they mean.

1. UI: 60.0 fps  ==> here 60.0 sometime is deceasing when I am working with my app.
2. X dopped so far ==> here x is the number which is increasing for mine it reached even 150 like:

`150 dropped so far`

3. X stutters (4+) so far ==> here x too is increasing

like: `12 stutters (4+) so far`

4. JS: 60.0 fps ==> here 60.0 decreased when I am working with app.

and finally what is `fps` it self in react-native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FPS means "Frame per Second". A "smooth" app should run at 60fps, most of the time. Most phones nowadays have 60hz displays (meaning they only refresh 60 times per second), and thus only high-end phones will be able to display more than 60 frames in a second. There's a few things you can do to ensure your RN app is running at optimal speed.

- As you may already know crossing the "bridge" (Javascript -> Native) is slow, and causes stuttering / low FPS. There's a lot of material out there explaining how this bridge works in detail, so I won't talk much about it. Try to minimise the amount of work being done (specially bridge crosses) during screen transitions or animations. You can do this by using the `InteractionManager` API. Read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager).
- Don't forget to read the official documentation on [Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance).
- If you're noticing lag right after opening a new screen, try deferring the rendering until the screen has fully transitioned into the viewport. An example of how to do this:

```js
import { View, InteractionManager } from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { ready: false };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // After all interactions have been finished we swich the "ready" state variable to true, and only then your component will be rendered.
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
            this.setState({ ready: true });
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.ready) { 
            return; 
        }

        // Render only when this.state.ready is true (after all interactions have been finalised);
        return (
            <View></View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer,
One of the biggest problem I am facing with react-native is scrolling the flatlist items
it doesnt works smoothly and appears blank area and dropped frame reached even to 1000

Comment: and please tell a little bit about dropped frame
is that mean frames which failed to be displayed?

Comment: Frame drop: as said above, 60 frames per second is what we consider "smooth". If you divide one second (1000ms) by 60 (frames we want in a second), you'll end up with 16.7ms (rounded). This means that if your code is taking more than 16ms to generate a frame (or complete a loop - search for JS event loop) it will be dropped by the system and then you'll have what we call "stuttering", or missing frames.